# htaccess not caching php file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following rules in the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=62, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

and in my php file(test.php) i have the following code

```
echo "time: ".time();
```

So now when i request the file i am seeing that the cache control is applied but the server is not providing the cache version.

For the record, i am using xampp environment.

Comment: [APCu](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a Cache-Control header in a response, as you're doing here, only directs clients to cache the page. It doesn't trigger any server-side caching.

(Additionally, clicking the reload button in a browser will ignore the Cache-Control header and always request the content from the server again. That's the whole point of reloading the page, after all!)

Comment: Any recommendation to how to make the server respond with a cached version instead of running the script again ?